# Dehydrated Fish Bone Broth

Tags: fish, broth

I'm trying to determine conversion for US. - dry teaspoons to ounces and grams, namely 1 tsp, 1-1/2 tsp, and 2 tsp. Every conversion table I've seen shows different values. The one I often found was: 3t, 1/2 oz, 14.3 g. If there is consensus, I'll just work it backward, but I really want this to be right!

Comment: It's there a reason you can't weigh your ingredients?

Comment: @bruglesco Not everyone has a kitchen scale, particularly in the US where recipe standard measurements are in teaspoons or cups. (And while having a kitchen scale IS nice, it's not necessarily the only answer to this dilemma!)

Comment: @Erica I live and work in the US where scales are in fact the de facto way of measuring weights. And yes a scale is the best solution to difficulties with weight measurement conversions.

Comment: Measuring solids by volume is a gigantic error. Try and measure a cup of shifted or packed flour and then compare its weight. There'll be a huge difference.

Comment: @bruglesco I'm just saying that sometimes conversion is more convenient. I own a kitchen scale, and I understand its improved accuracy for cooking — and I still almost always measure by teaspoon rather than weight.

Comment: @bruglesco - It seems what I really needed was a little perspective here. Thank you. Yes, I do have a scale. 1 tsp = .4 oz. I got it - I appreciate all the valuable input here. Thank you!!

Comment: @JudeGilford glad to be of help. Just remember that weight to volume won't always be the same. Think packed flour yo loose as someone says earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Part of your problem, as stated, is attempting to convert volume measurements to mass measurements. You cannot do that without knowing the bulk density of the materials and tossing that factor into the equation ie. a tablespoom of cornstarch (UK corn flour) does not have the same mass as a tablespoon of fine salt. (In the USA, think weight instead of mass though it is technically incorrect)
One great little program I use for conversions is found at https://joshmadison.com/convert-for-windows/. It is free!
If working with a Roolander's recipe, try to remember that their tablespoons have 20ml volume not 15ml as is common in much of the rest of the world.

Comment: Yes one the problems seems to be mixing volume and mass.

Comment: 3t = 1T = 1/2 oz as volume where 8oz=1 cup etc. As mass (ie converting to kg)  16 oz= 1 lb.  The oz weight and oz volume coincide for water I believe but other than that no means of converting without other information.